# lsFusion: The starting year for a 100-year period, if the year is specified by a two-digit number

Tags: localization, open-source, lsfusion

Good afternoon, "The starting year for a 100-year period, if the year is specified by a two-digit number" What is [the setting](https://docs.lsfusion.org/Internationalization/#current) about?

[image: Internationalization-current locale]

Like here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this setting is for dates where the year is specified by two digits. If, for example, 1930 is specified, all two-digit years >= 30 will be 19xx, and all less than that will be 20xx.

if you enter the date from the keyboard. The date format on the server is not always set to 4 digits or when importing may use.
We have a short format in the projects usually:

```
user.defaultDateFormat=dd.MM.yy
user.dateFormat=dd.MM.yy
```